# Cannot get CSS form to line-up Properly

Tags: html, css

The page in question is: http://stpsormd.com/

Under the "Add Equipment" section, the second row of textbox elements will not float left properly. In Dreamweaver which is what I'm using to organize the code, it lines up correctly but in Google Chrome it wants to shift to the second column of form fields.

For those digging through the code, only the index.php and primary.css files should have any relation to this particular problem.  As a note, I did not have this problem when all of the form fields were textboxes, changing two of them to option boxes made the shift that I cannot explain.

The top row does add up to 930px in width which is the width of the container, same as the form fields in the "Add User" section.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how you want them to be alligned?

Comment: Exactly as the "Add User" section is.  I want the misaligned "Code" label and textbox to fall directly under the "Serial" field above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a clear: left; (or both) to that "formlabel float" div. That fixes it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I had tried that but must not. Your solution is in place and working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
.formlabel {
    left:0px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I have put that code in place now, it renders exactly the same unfortunately.